# Как считать строки из файла начав с определенного номера строки?

Tags: python

Как осуществить последовательное чтение строк из файла, начав с определенного номера строки?

Comment: У вас ответ дан в тексте вопроса. Задайте вопрос, и дайте на него ответ отдельно.

Comment: Искал ответ и в ходе поиска сам и решил. Думаю другим будет интересно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Считать строки из файла с определённого номера строки можно с помощью следующего кода

```
fileName = 'data.txt'
n = 9 # Нумерация строк в файле будет с 0

f = open(fileName, 'r')
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    line = line.replace("\n", "")
    if i >= n:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 4):

Файл является итератором над строками в Питоне. Можно использовать [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), чтобы заданный диапазон строк получить:

```
lines = islice(file, n, None)
```

Для улучшения производительности для больших файлов можно попробовать использовать `mmap` и искать индекс вхождения `b'\n'` (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import os
import mmap

@contextlib.contextmanager
def tail_kth_mmap(filename, k=0, newline=os.linesep.encode()):
    """Return mmap positioned at the k-th line."""
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file, \
         mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        i = -1
        for _ in range(k):
            i = s.find(newline, i+1)
            if i == -1: # file is too small
                break
        if i != -1:
            s.seek(min(i + len(newline), s.size()))
        elif k > 0:
            s.seek(0, 2) # EOF
        yield s
```

Пример, чтобы напечатать `data.txt`, начиная с `n`-ой строки:

```
with tail_kth_mmap('data.txt', k=n) as s:
    shutil.copyfileobj(s, sys.stdout.buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще один пример, как по мне очень наглядный и простой

```
lines=[25, 29] # диапазон строк
i=0 # индекс
f=open('/path/file.txt')
for line in f:
    if i in lines:
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример из предыдущего ответа не работал, исправил, проверил - работает:

```
file_name = 'filename'
with open(filename, 'r') as text_file:
    lines = [0, 1, 2]  # диапазон строк
    i = 0    
    for line in text_file:
        if i in lines:
            i += 1
            print('line: ', line)
        else:
            i +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM_LINE = 100

with open("input.txt") as infile:
    for __ in range(FROM_LINE):
        next(infile)
    for row in infile:
        print(row)
```

Объяснение:

1. `infile` - это *итератор*, потому  к нему возможно применить стандартную функцию `next()` для выдачи (или пропуска) следующей строки файла.
2. В первом цикле его переменная не используется — потому я  применил для неё странное имя `__`.
3. После перехода первым циклом в итераторе `infile` уже первых `FROM_LINE` строк нет, потому второй цикл выдает только остальные строки файла.

Comment: Вы повторили функциональность [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). Правильнее следовать первому ответу не изобретая велосипед.