# readlines() в Python, как сэкономить время и память?

Tags: python

Понадобилось из кучи файлов (около 200 000) прочитать 6 и 9 строку, первое что пришло на ум:

```
f = open('ED3204867.zks', 'r')
line = f.readlines()[6]
print line
f.close()
```

Но есть файлы размером до 10М (очевидно картинки вложены), в общем я так понимаю readlines() в данном случае не очень эффективен поскольку читает весь файл в память?

Может так?

```
x=1
while x < 10:
    line = f.readline()
    if x == 6:
        print line
    x++
f.close()
```

Какой вариант быстрее?
Может есть еще более эффективный способ?

Comment: Если у вас там бинарные файлы, то вы не можете прочитать у них шестую и девятую строку. В бинарных файлах нету понятия "строка", поэтому f.readline() может вернуть вам все те же десять мегабайт, я бы на вашем месте в первую очередь решал бы проблему отсеивания бинарных файлов.

Comment: xml там простой, cat EE3674814.zks | more прекрасно выводит содекржимое. Что касается  картинок так в fb2 их как то зашивают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень длинных строк нет, то можно `itertools.islice()` использовать, чтобы шестую и девятую строку прочитать из файла (*начиная с первой*):

```
import itertools

with open(filename) as file:
    lines = list(itertools.islice(file, 5, 9))
    sixth, ninth = lines[0], lines[3]
```

Чтобы промежуточные строки все в памяти не держать и если известно что файл содержит не менее девяти строк, то можно `collections.deque()` использовать:

```
import collections
import itertools

with open(filename) as file:
    lines = itertools.islice(file, 5, 9)
    sixth = next(lines)
    ninth, = collections.deque(lines, maxlen=1)
```

Если файл может содержать очень длинные строки, то можно адаптировать `mmap` код из [Как считать строки из файла начав с определенного номера строки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485251/23044)

Answer (score 2):

```
fileName = 'data.txt'
n = [6, 9] # Нумерация строк в файле будет с 0

m = max(n)
f = open(fileName, 'r')
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i>m:
        break
    line = line.replace("\n", "")
    if i in n:
        print(line)
```