# Переход на заданную строку

Tags: python, файлы

Здравствуйте, можно ли как-нибудь в питоне перейти в файле на заданную строку, то есть мне не надо читать его полностью, а например прочитать с третьей по пятую строку, при этом в я не знаю сколько в байтах содержит каждая из них?

Comment: по-моему так не получится - можно либо один раз прочитать файл полностью, запоминая позицию (`file_object.tell()`) начала каждой строки или если вы постоянно дописываете в файл, созранять/записывать позиции строк по мере добавления...

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Как считать строки из файла начав с определенного номера строки?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485235/23044)

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [readlines() в Python, как сэкономить время и память?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485294/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как счет начинается с нуля то у третьей строки индекс будет 2, у пятой 4

filename - имя файла

`text = open(filename, 'r').readlines()[2:4]`

получаем список из нужных строк

 `text = '\n'.join(text)`

соединяем строки в одну, но с переносами

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам воспользоваться ConfigParser, он наиболее подойдёт для вашей задумки. Вот Вики для примеров https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples

Comment: не могли бы вы привести пример - как можно прочитать с третьей по пятую строку произвольного текстового файла (в котором отсутствуют секции - `[section]`) при помощи ConfigParser'а?

Comment: У меня действительно есть такие секции в  файле, но в общем случае этот способ, видимо, не работает.

Comment: @MaxU если секции отсутствуют, прочитать никак